# How to insert data to table using loop.?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I want to insert data in database table using loop. For this I first need to get data of `Account_id` from `user profile` table. When user is registered with my website, his/her name table is create automatically, I am storing this table name in `Account_id`. that's why I must need this field.

First I get all registered users `Account_id` value. And then I am searching this table using for loop in model.

After I find this table, the row should be inserted, which is created dynamically like

```
$data = array(
    'Paper_Name' => $paper_name,
    'Paper_Type' => $paper_type,
    'paid_type' => $paid_type
);
```

Here is my model code.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class create_main_table_model extends CI_Model {

    function login($data){

        $query = $this->db->insert('main_table', $data);    

        $update_userdata = $this->db->select('Account_id')->from('userprofile')->get();

                for($i =0; $i < $update_userdata->num_rows(); $i++){

                        $query = $this->db->insert($update_userdata[$i], $data);    

                }

        return ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) ? true : false;
    }
}
?>
```

I want to Insert data to tables which is available in `Account_id`.
If this is possible with other way then please tell me.

Comment: And the issue is???

Comment: $this->db->insert ( $table, $data );  this is insert query in codeigniter

Comment: your almost right change this line  $query = $this->db->insert($update_userdata[$i]->Account_id, $data);

Comment: you need to update the already existing row or you need new row ?

Comment: did you tried my answer

Answer (score 3):

This is perfect solution.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class create_main_table_model extends CI_Model {

    function login($data){

        $pass_data = $data;
        $query = $this->db->insert('main_table', $data);    

        $update_userdata = $this->db->select('Account_id')->from('userprofile')->get();

                for($i =0; $i < $update_userdata->num_rows(); $i++){
                        $data1 = $update_userdata->result();
                        $query = $this->db->insert($data1[$i]->Account_id, $pass_data); 

                }

        return ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) ? true : false;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your almost right change this line to get the `table name` .

```
$update_userdata = $this->db->$update_userdata->result();
$query = $this->db->insert($update_userdata[$i]->Account_id, $data);
```

Comment: I must get result before using this . like`$this->db->$update_userdata->result();`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class create_main_table_model extends CI_Model {

    function login($data){

        $query = $this->db->insert('main_table', $data);    

        $update_userdata = $this->db->select('Account_id')->from('userprofile')->get();

                for($i =0; $i < $update_userdata->num_rows(); $i++){

                $data['Account_id']=$update_userdata[$i]->Account_id;

                $query = $this->db->insert('table_name', $data);    

                }

        return ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) ? true : false;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I want to tell you again table name is `Account_id`. so use it as table name